# How to remove section from system.xml file?

Tags: system.xml

System.xml file consist of different sections. Now I want to remove particular section from it

I tried by creating module in etc folder and system file in local folder but in vain.

For e.g I want to remove "gift options" from Sales configuration page in admin panel. how to remove it..?

I dont want to do from core folder

Is there any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code it worked for me

**app\etc\modules\Myname_Mymodule.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
         <Myname_Mymodule>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_GiftMessage />
            </depends>
        </Myname_Mymodule>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**app\code\local\Myname\Mymodule\etc\config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Myname_Mymodule>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Myname_Mymodule>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**app\code\local\Myname\Mymodule\etc\system.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <sections>
        <sales>
            <groups>
                <gift_options translate="label" module="giftmessage">
                    <label>Gift Options </label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>0</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                 </gift_options>
            </groups>
        </sales>
    </sections>
</config>
```

Comment: I have written same code but its not working....I am not getting why it is still visible

Comment: Please clear cache and then try make sure all files will be on right palace.

Comment: cache is already disable..I have cleared browser cache also then to it is visible

Comment: Can you share your codes here along with file path ??

Comment: I have written same code which you have given in the same file path which you have mention

Comment: what is your Magento version ?

Comment: Magento version is 1.9

Comment: in system.xml what will be module name?

Comment: I am also using this code in 1.9 it's working.Module name will be  "giftmessage"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29967/discussion-between-arunendra-and-donika).

Answer (score 8):

system.xml can not be override but you can hide section by creating module
put below code in your modules system.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>  
<config>
    <sections>
        <sales>
            <groups>
                <gift_options translate="label" module="giftmessage">                    
                    <show_in_default>0</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                </gift_options>
            </groups>
        </sales>
    </sections>
</config>
```

Make sure your module depends on Mage_GiftMessage

Comment: here in above code module name will be my module name??

Comment: yes name your module as you want

Comment: @Donika you can accept this answer if working fine at your end

Comment: It is still visible ..I am not getting the problem

Comment: @Donika clear cache first and check

Comment: cache is already disable..I have cleared browser cache also then to it is visible